# How can I add an "add contact" button like the Contacts application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I add to my app that little "plus" button that the Contacts application has in the upper right hand corner of the window?

I would like to be able to hit that button and bring up a screen to add a new entry to the table view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're talking about is a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Here's an example of how to set one up in code:

```
UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showContactView:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
[addButton release];
```

When tapped, the button will call the follow selector.

```
- (void)showContactView:(id)sender {
    // Show new contact view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tom Irving is completely right. It is a UIBarButton and you can configure as he has said. It can be added to a UINavigationBar or UIToolbar as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Also dont forget to release this button because some times it causes a crash if you dont release the button instance.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment to Tom's answer, excluding the restatement of Tom being right. If you think someone is right, up vote their answer. If you have something to add to their answer either add it as a comment or, if you have enough reputation, edit their answer.

Comment: Jasarein I am new on this site. Neways Sorry. Also i was the first to give an up vote to Tom. So you better dont worry about it.